# ActionScript - Show frame and then execute a fscommand("exec"

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I've never developed for ActionScript or flash, and maybe this is a simple question.

I created a menu in flash (Projector in a CD-ROM Autorun), where users can choose what program they will install.

In the last frame, I'm **trying** to show a message like: "*Thanks, your installation will start in few seconds. Wait while the program is loading.*".

The installation program loads, and then flash menu closes. That's ok.

I inserted this code in Actions of the frame :

```
fscommand("exec", "MyInstallationProgram.Exe");
fscommand("quit");
```

It works, but the frame doens't render, I'd like to show the frame while the program is loading. How can I do it?

I am using ActionScript 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `fscommand('quit')` is closing the application before your dialogue has a chance to display.

As far as I know, there is no simple way of communicating back to your launcher application that the selected program has installed. Your best bet, therefore, is probably to quit automatically after a few seconds:

```
// Add to frame with dialogue
stop();

setInterval(function(){
    fscommand('quit');
}, 5000); // Automatically quit after 5 seconds
```

Alternatively you could add the `fscommand('quit')` call to the handler for a 'close' button under the dialogue.